# Compute the evolution of percentages from a data file

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting

My data is stored in external .out files which contain six columns and a large number of rows. I know that I have to provide a small sample but the structure of my data is so unique, so I provide the entire data file here: [data](http://www.mediafire.com/download/2v0is2223j0jvs4/RTBP.out)

This time we need only columns 1, 2 and 6. The first column contains the `x` position, second column the corresponding energy `E`, while the six column has only integers regarding a classification. Now if we plot in a 2D diagram the first two columns assigning in every point a color according the value of the six column we get the following

[image]

Now I want to do the following. For every value of `E` we have several values of `x` with different classification. The possible integers of the sixth column are: {-1, 1, 2, 11, 12, 21, 22, 31, 32, 99}. I want to compute how many -1, 1, 2, ..., 99 are for the first value of `E` and compute the corresponding percentages. Then go to the next value of `E` and repeat the procedure. Thus we can follow the evolution of percentages as a function of `E`. The ultimate goal is to create a diagram showing all together with the corresponding colors the 10 trend lines.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

And here is a small data sample as minimal working example

```
{{-5.`, -3, 24.89`, 
 0.8079019748736321`, -1, -1}, {-4.977477477477477`, -3, 24.72`, 
 0.8100409238103935`, -1, 1}, {-4.954954954954955`, -3, 24.54`, 
 0.8122953345427153`, -1, 2}, {-4.932432432432432`, -3, 24.36`, 
 0.8145539903185015`, -1, 21}, {-4.90990990990991`, -3, 24.19`, 
 0.8167060089472148`, -1, -1}, {-4.887387387387387`, -3, 24.01`, 
 0.8189737833735357`, -1, -1}, {-4.864864864864865`, -3, 23.84`, 
 0.8211357279224385`, -1, -1}, {-4.842342342342342`, -3, 23.67`, 
 0.823303331789986`, -1, 99}, {-4.81981981981982`, -2, 23.5`, 
 0.8254770541856945`, -1, -1}, {-4.797297297297297`, -2, 23.32`, 
 0.8277682452908253`, -1, 32}, {-4.774774774774775`, -2, 23.15`, 
 0.8299553813547601`, -1, 21}, {-4.752252252252252`, -2, 22.98`, 
 0.8321495854317591`, -1, 11}, {-4.72972972972973`, -2, 22.82`, 
 0.8342399060011664`, -1, -1}, {-4.707207207207207`, -2, 22.65`, 
 0.8364482241698246`, -1, 2}, {-4.684684684684685`, -2, 22.48`, 
 0.8386633336338121`, -1, -1}, {-4.662162162162162`, -1, 22.31`, 
 0.8408848961319084`, -1, 22}, {-4.63963963963964`, -1, 22.15`, 
 0.843001699453557`, -1, 12}, {-4.617117117117117`, -1, 21.98`, 
 0.8452350102456677`, -1, 1}, {-4.594594594594595`, -1, 21.81`, 
 0.8474735570160751`, -1, 2}, {-4.572072072072072`, -1, 21.65`, 
 0.8496066341065539`, -1, 11}, {-4.54954954954955`, -1, 21.49`, 
 0.8517447815274005`, -1, 32}, {-4.527027027027027`, 0, 21.32`, 
 0.8539977804973352`, -1, -1}, {-4.504504504504505`, 0, 21.16`, 
 0.8561457246831677`, -1, 2}, {-4.481981981981982`, 0, 21.`, 
 0.8582989136727225`, -1, 1}, {-4.45945945945946`, 0, 20.83`, 
 0.8605668266689402`, -1, 11}, {-4.436936936936937`, 0, 20.67`, 
 0.862731269804195`, -1, -21}, {-4.414414414414415`, 1, 20.51`, 
 0.8649021245634532`, -1, 22}, {-4.391891891891892`, 1, 20.35`, 
 0.8670798666925034`, -1, -1}, {-4.36936936936937`, 1, 20.19`, 
 0.8692649521543424`, -1, 2}, {-4.346846846846847`, 1, 20.03`, 
 0.8714577803779188`, -1, 1}, {-4.324324324324325`, 1, 19.88`, 
 0.873550635695638`, -1, 32}, {-4.301801801801802`, 1, 19.72`, 
 0.8757599471643019`, -1, 99}, {-4.27927927927928`, 1, 19.56`, 
 0.8779776273998509`, -1, 11}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
 p[list_] := (#/Total[#]) &@(Count[list, #] & /@ {-1, 1, 2, 11, 12, 21,22, 31, 32, 99} );
 x = {#[[1, 2]], p@ #[[All, 6]]} & /@ GatherBy[ data ,  #[[2]] & ];

 ListPlot[ Table[ {#[[1]], #[[2, i]]} & /@ x , {i, 1, 10}] , Joined -> True]
```

[image]

somewhat cleaner alternate form:

```
p[list_] := #/Total[#] &@
      BinCounts[ list, { {-1, 1, 2, 11, 12, 21, 22, 31, 32, 99, Infinity} }];
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I what. Just a minor comment. Now the percentage is expressed in decimal between [0, 1]. How can I change it to % between [0, 100]?

Comment: just put `100` in here: `(100 #/Total[#])`

Comment: Many many thanks!