# Compute the evolution of several quanties from a data file

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting

This question is somehow a part II of this: [Part I](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71398/compute-the-evolution-of-percentages-from-a-data-file).

Here comes a small data sample as a minimal working example:

```
{{-5.`, -3, 24.89`, 
0.8079019748736321`, -1, -1}, {-4.977477477477477`, -3, 24.72`, 
0.8100409238103935`, -1, 1}, {-4.954954954954955`, -3, 24.54`, 
0.8122953345427153`, -1, 2}, {-4.932432432432432`, -3, 24.36`, 
0.8145539903185015`, -1, 0}, {-4.90990990990991`, -3, 24.19`, 
0.8167060089472148`, -1, -1}, {-4.887387387387387`, -3, 24.01`, 
0.8189737833735357`, -1, -1}, {-4.864864864864865`, -3, 23.84`, 
0.8211357279224385`, -1, -1}, {-4.842342342342342`, -3, 23.67`, 
0.823303331789986`, -1, 0}, {-4.81981981981982`, -2, 23.5`, 
0.8254770541856945`, -1, -1}, {-4.797297297297297`, -2, 23.32`, 
0.8277682452908253`, -1, 2}, {-4.774774774774775`, -2, 23.15`, 
0.8299553813547601`, -1, 1}, {-4.752252252252252`, -2, 22.98`, 
0.8321495854317591`, -1, 2}, {-4.72972972972973`, -2, 22.82`, 
0.8342399060011664`, -1, -1}, {-4.707207207207207`, -2, 22.65`, 
0.8364482241698246`, -1, 2}, {-4.684684684684685`, -2, 22.48`, 
0.8386633336338121`, -1, -1}, {-4.662162162162162`, -1, 22.31`, 
0.8408848961319084`, -1, 0}, {-4.63963963963964`, -1, 22.15`, 
0.843001699453557`, -1, 1}, {-4.617117117117117`, -1, 21.98`, 
0.8452350102456677`, -1, 1}, {-4.594594594594595`, -1, 21.81`, 
0.8474735570160751`, -1, 2}, {-4.572072072072072`, -1, 21.65`, 
0.8496066341065539`, -1, 0}, {-4.54954954954955`, -1, 21.49`, 
0.8517447815274005`, -1, 2}, {-4.527027027027027`, 0, 21.32`, 
0.8539977804973352`, -1, -1}, {-4.504504504504505`, 0, 21.16`, 
0.8561457246831677`, -1, 2}, {-4.481981981981982`, 0, 21.`, 
0.8582989136727225`, -1, 1}, {-4.45945945945946`, 0, 20.83`, 
0.8605668266689402`, -1, 0}, {-4.436936936936937`, 0, 20.67`, 
0.862731269804195`, -1, -1}, {-4.414414414414415`, 1, 20.51`, 
0.8649021245634532`, -1, 2}, {-4.391891891891892`, 1, 20.35`, 
0.8670798666925034`, -1, -1}, {-4.36936936936937`, 1, 20.19`, 
0.8692649521543424`, -1, 2}, {-4.346846846846847`, 1, 20.03`, 
0.8714577803779188`, -1, 1}, {-4.324324324324325`, 1, 19.88`, 
0.873550635695638`, -1, 0}, {-4.301801801801802`, 1, 19.72`, 
0.8757599471643019`, -1, 0}, {-4.27927927927928`, 1, 19.56`, 
0.8779776273998509`, -1, 1}}
```

This time we need only columns 1, 2, 3 and 6. The first column contains the x position, the second column the corresponding energy E, the third  the time, while the sixth column has only integers regarding a classification.

Now I want to do the following. For every value of E we have several values of x with different classification. The possible integers of the sixth column are: {-1, 0, 1, 2}.

(a). I want to compute the mean value of the third column for the first value of E when the six column is either 1 or 2 (not -1 and 0). Then go to the next value of E and repeat the procedure. Thus we can follow the evolution of the mean value as a function of E.

(b). For the first value of E compute how many (the percentage) 1 and 2 with time (third column) < 23 exist. Then repeat this calculation for all the other values of E, so as to create a plot showing the evolution of this percentage as a function of E.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a)

```
Mean[Cases[Data, {_, e_, x_, _, _, i_} /; e == # && (i == 1 || i == 2) -> {e, x}]] & /@ 
  Range[-3, 1]
(* {{-3, 24.63}, {-2, 23.025}, {-1, 21.8575}, {0, 21.08}, {1, 20.0725}} *)
```

(b)

```
lyes = Count[Data, {_, e_, t_, _, _, i_} /; e == # && t < 23 && (i == 1 || i == 2)]& /@ 
  Range[-3, 1]    
ltot = Count[Data, {_, e_, t_, _, _, i_} /; e == #]& /@ Range[-3, 1]
N[lyes/ltot]
(* {0., 0.285714, 0.666667, 0.4, 0.571429} *)
```

If, as indicated in a Comment, the values of `e` are not regularly spaced, they can be extracted directly from `Data`.

```
energies = Union[Cases[Data, {_, e_, t_, _, _, i_} -> e]]
(* {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1} *)
```

and `Range[-3, 1]` replaced by `energies` in the expressions above.

Comment: Time is the third column (I corrected the post). Now let me explain better point (b). Let's take the first energy level `E = -3`. It contains items where the sixth column is -1, 0, 1, 2. I want to find how many of these have 1 or 2 at the sixth column but also when time is lower than 23 (a combined criterion). If the number of the items is `n` and there is `ntot` items with `E = -3` then the desired percentage is `(n/not)*100`. Then of course the same procedure should be repeated for all other energy levels.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `(n/{n + not))*100`?

Comment: I tested your solution to my actual data file but there is a problem. You see in the real data file the energy is between -3 and 0 and can take also decimal figures (i.e., -1.1, etc), so `Range[-3,0]` does not work because the step is not known.

Comment: `(n/not)*100` is the correct. `n` is the number of items with sixth column equal to 1 or 2 with third column less then 23, while `not` is the total amount of items for a given energy level.

Comment: Next, is shall handle the more general case you just introduced.

Comment: `lyes` does not take into account the criterion `t < 23` and as I explained `Range[-3,1]` does not work in the real data file.

Comment: Yes, I copied the wrong line of code, omitting `&& t<23`.  Thanks for point it out.  I have fixed that typo and generalized the solutions for irregularly spaced `e`.

Comment: Now everything works OK however, the code needs about 3 min to calculate the values. I assume that there must be a faster solution. Just a minor comment for point (b). How can I create a table containing for every energy level the corresponding percentage, so I can use directly `ListPlot`?

Comment: Use `Thread[{energies, Map[ToString[100 #] <> "%" &, N[lyes/ltot]]}] // TableForm` to obtain a table of percentages.  See my new edit for a slight speed improvement.